# How to Change Citation Style in LyX?

Tags: citing

I tried Natbib Author-year in Document Settings, but I get

> **(author?)** [2, 3]

How do I get [FSS81], instead of [1]?

Comment: Which bibliography style file do you use, and which citation commands do you use?